# Proving a certain behavior of zeros of an analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

[image]

This is an exercise from Conway that I am stuck at. First, how can I use the proposition 5.4 (put below) to prove it? I cannot see how $log$ function can come in. Also I am stuck at (b) too. I know the definition of Blaschke product and I solved the exercise 5.4 mentioned here. But I cannot solve (b)... Could anyone please help me?[image]

This is proposition 5.4.
[image]

This is the exercise 5.4 of the chapter 7 about Blaschke products.

Comment: Could you give me more hints please?

Comment: If $\sum_n (1-|a_n|) < \infty$ then $G(z) = f(z) z^{-m} \frac{1}{B(z)}$ is analytic and non-zero on $D$. By the maximum modulus principle and the properties of Blaschke product, $\sup_{z\in D} |G(z)|$ is easily seen to be what your book said. More precisely, do you know what is $\sup_{z\in D} |B(z)|$ and $\inf_{z\in D} |B(z)|$ ?

Comment: Of course I know what supremum and infinum are. Specifically what properties of Blaschke product are used? Also, could you give me some hints about (a)?

Comment: Your book probably already showed a bound for $\sum_n (1-|a_n|)$ in term of things like [Jensen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_formula)

Comment: Yes the book proved Jensen formula. But how does the formula has to do with the bound for the series?

Comment: $\log(1+x) \sim x$ so $\sum_n \log|a_n|$ converges iff $\sum_n (1-|a_n|)$ does. But did you understand proving a) from scratch has nothing trivial ?

Comment: That is the point where I am stuck. How can I show that the sum of  log a_n converges?

Comment: Replace $f(z)$ by $f(z) z^{-m}$ so that $\log f(0) \ne 0$ and look at the sign of each term in Jensen formula when $r \to 1^-$

Comment: I managed to solve (a). However I have trouble finding $g$ with the inequality satisfied. Could you give me hints on that?